# I have removed the text that made my question sound like a resource request; can it be re-opened now?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

As best I can tell, [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413705/parsing-natural-language-ingredient-quantities-for-recipes) got closed because of a few lines at the bottom and possibly the tagging. I have removed/rephrased the lines that made it sound like I was asking for someone to find an off-site resource.

Is there anything else that I need to change in order to make this question eligible for re-opening? It seemed like a popular question, so I'd like to salvage it, if possible.

Comment: The question you actually ask is "Are there any tricks to this?" which is too broad regardless of what "this" is. Moreover it's unclear what you mean by "this". Moreover whatever it is seems from the large exposition like when it's clear it's going to be too broad. Look at the answers. They're just random suggestions for natural language processing. You do say "I'm wondering", but that's too broad, and .... you're wondering seeks ... tools. (Also, "best" doesn't mean anything unless you define it clearly enough that we could unabiguously agree on evaluations.)

Comment: Closing a question means that it will no more accept answers. There are plenty of answers and one is accepted. Closing is not forcibly deleting. What bothers you?

Comment: @Vega He or she probably thinks it should be open and accepting more answers. Maybe there have been new developments in the last years.